# Transition SVG TopoJSON Map Left and Right on Mobile Viewport

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, css-transitions, react-transition-group

I have an SVG TopoJSON map - centered within the viewport (see attached image) - of the US on a mobile screen and I am looking to transition the map right and left when a user clicks on an arrow. I have tried `window.scrollTo()`, but that shifts the entire experience right/left and not just the map - there is more content above the map so this doesn't work. Does anyone know a way to simply "slide" the map component/container?

[image: centered US map]

Comment: If the SVG has a viewBox then adjust that.